# ffmpeg: How to move text from bottom right to Center of screen

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to move a text from the bottom right (outside background) to the center of the screen. The black text should go exactlly where the green text is.

This is what I have tryed:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -loop 0 -i "color=color=yellow:size=800x400,drawtext=text='Test':fontsize=70:font='Arial Black':fontcolor=green:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2,drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=black:fontsize=70:font='Arial Black':x=W-(t)*((W+tw)/2)/6:y=x*(H/W):enable='between(t,0,6)'"
```

[image: gif]

Comment: ffmpeg certainly can do a lot of stuff. I'm not convinced it was made to do this though. That's something I would use video editing software for. No specific recommendation though, sorry.

Comment: You can do it by scrolling a .png of the text by using a scrolling overlay. However it requires a lot of calculations to control where and when it arrives at its end point, and because of the difference in vertical and horizontal movement, smoothness is an issue. This can partly be resolved, but you would be better off looking at a video editor as Daniel suggested.

Comment: try this: `:x=(W-tw)-(t-2)/4*(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)-(t-2)/4*(H-th)/2:enable='lt(t,6)'`

Comment: That would go to the center of the screen but the moving text doesn't start on the right position right botton outer corner....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math may be a bit complicated, but it's possible...

Assume we know from advance: W=`800`, H=`400`, tw=`170`, th=`54`.
We may pre-calculate the following parameters:

```
alpha = atan2(H, W) = atan2(400, 800)   
sin_alpha = sin(alpha) = 0.4472136 alternately: sin_alpha = H/sqrt(W*W+H*H)  
cos_alpha = cos(alpha) = 0.8944272 alternately: cos_alpha = W/sqrt(W*W+H*H)

tw = 170
th = 54

radius = sqrt((W/2+tw/2)^2 + (H/2+th/2)^2) = sqrt((400+85)^2 + (200+27)^2) = 535.5
step = radius / duration = radius / 6 = 89.249

r = radius - t*step = 535.5 - t*3.57
center_x = W/2 + r*cos_alpha
center_y = H/2 + r*sin_alpha
x = center_x - tw/2 = W/2 + r*cos_alpha - tw/2 = 400+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.8944272-85
y = center_y - th/2 = H/2 + r*sin_alpha - th/2 = 200+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.4472136-27
```

---

FFplay command:

`ffplay -f lavfi -loop 0 -i "color=color=yellow:size=800x400,drawtext=text='Test':fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:fontcolor=green:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2,drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=black:fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:x=(400+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.8944272-85):y=(200+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.4472136-27):enable='between(t,0,6)'"`

---

FFmpeg command for creating `test.gif`:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=color=yellow:size=800x400:duration=6,format=rgb24,drawtext=text='Test':fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:fontcolor=green:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2,drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=black:fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:x=(400+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.8944272-85):y=(200+(535.5-t*89.249)*0.4472136-27):enable='between(t,0,6)',split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" test.gif`

---

Replacing all the constants, and using only W, H, tw, th:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=color=yellow:size=800x400:duration=6,format=rgb24,drawtext=text='Test':fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:fontcolor=green:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2,drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=black:fontsize=70:fontfile=ariblk.ttf:x=(W/2+(sqrt((W/2+tw/2)*(W/2+tw/2)+(H/2+th/2)*(H/2+th/2))-t*sqrt((W/2+tw/2)*(W/2+tw/2)+(H/2+th/2)*(H/2+th/2))/6)*W/sqrt(W*W+H*H)-tw/2):y=(H/2+(sqrt((W/2+tw/2)*(W/2+tw/2)+(H/2+th/2)*(H/2+th/2))-t*sqrt((W/2+tw/2)*(W/2+tw/2)+(H/2+th/2)*(H/2+th/2))/6)*H/sqrt(W*W+H*H)-th/2):enable='between(t,0,6)',split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" test.gif`

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: The gif you posted seems right but when I use your code the black text goes slightly more to the left: https://s12.gifyu.com/images/SWcun.gif

Comment: I'm on Windows, I think this part don't work here: fontfile='ariablk.ttf', when I use font='Arial Black' instead it works.

Comment: What is sqrt? Is it possible to do this without pré-calculations? Puting all in one command line?

Comment: I am using Windows too. font='Arial Black'  didn't work. I had to copy 'ariablk.ttf' to the working folder. I added a solution without pre-calculations. `sqrt` is square root.

Comment: thank you very much